# UITableViewCell auto created code?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {   
        CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(42, 7, 245, 30);
        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
```

I saw the above code in many places and I'm wondering, what's the source of that chunk of code? Can xcode auto create it when i do something with the GUI?

If not, what about `CGRectMake(42, 7, 245, 30)` how can i set those numbers without counting pixels?

Thanks

Comment: r u aware of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I'm aware of the class but i don't understand how come every source code online got the above code. Where is coming from?

Comment: wat do you mean online, am seeing first time in ur post..

Comment: If i'll google UITableViewCell I'll find many examples using the same or something very similar to the above code. Is it something generic that apple gives or is it something that is auto created in Xcode when i do something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain you,

A `UITableViewCell` is just a view/object representing each row/cell in a tableView. Apple has some predefined styles of `UITableViewCell` with lables, imageView and other objects.

You may add any objects on this cell like other views, creating objects w.r.t frame & add on cell's content View.

You may be seeing the same code everywhere is just it is the simplest way to create a custom cell of your own `UITableViewCell`. Either apple may be using this as a default when created a new project with a tableView template. Or it may be copied down from the same reference to explain in their own styles in their own tutorials.

This may be just a coincidence.

Comment: To my understanding the above code is some kind of a cell template apple provids. For example, 2 lines, image on the left etc'. I'm trying to find the original code for those templates or to understand how to create it in xcode without typing it all over again.

Comment: once you check by creating a new project in xcode with master detail template, and check what code is created..